# Setting content as 'hidden' by default

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I would like to set the below content as hidden by default. The code is working fine but it's displaying all the content when you land on the page.

```css
.show {
  display: none;
}

.hide:focus+.show {
  display: inline;
}

.hide:focus {
  display: none;
}

.hide:focus~#list {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  .hide,
  .show {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click below to learn how to access LearnHub and the services available to employees.</p>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="hide">[hide]</a>
  <a href="#" class="show">[show]</a>
  <ol id="list">
    <p>
      <h2>How to access LearnHub</h2>
      <p>1. Click on the LearnHub button under ‘Business Systems' on the Intranet home page.</p>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: What "content"? All the child of `<body>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the element with the ID of `list` to be invisible when the page loads, add an entry into the CSS to set its `display` property to `none`.

```
#list {display:none;}
```

You'll also need to add the opposites or complements of many of the CSS rules you currently have in place, as demonstrated in the snippet below:

```css
#list {
  display: none;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show:focus+.hide {
  display: inline;
}
.show:focus {
  display: none;
}
.show:focus~#list {
  display: inline;
}
.hide:focus+.show {
  display: inline;
}
.hide:focus {
  display: none;
}
.hide:focus~#list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="show">[show]</a>
  <a href="#" class="hide">[hide]</a>
  <ol id="list">
    <p>
      <h2>How to access LearnHub</h2>
      <p>1. Click on the LearnHub button under ‘Business Systems' on the Intranet home page.</p>
  </ol>
</div>
```